# Profiles script doesn't display correctly

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I'm setting up a new script, and I want support about it.Where do I need to change my code because is looking so weird right now.I want to display profiles in line, not two up and two down.Here is an example with correct way for display: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrrEU.jpg

**here is my code :**

```
<div class="tab-v2 margin-bottom-40">

<?php $count_user = 0; ?>
@foreach($user->contact as $contact)
@if($count_user == 0)
@endif
<?php $count_user++; ?>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">

    <li class="active">
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#contact1">
            <?php $img = asset('thumbnail').'/'.$contact->profile_picture; ?>
            <img class="img-circle noticeboard-profile-picture" src="{{ url('ass/50/50?'.$img) }}" alt=""></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#contact2">
                <?php $img = asset('thumbnail').'/'.$contact->profile_picture; ?>
                <img class="img-circle noticeboard-profile-picture" src="{{ url('ass/50/50?'.$img) }}" alt=""></a>
            </li>

        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="contact1" class="tab-pane magazine-sb-categories active">
                <div class="row team-v1">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled col-xs-12" style="margin-bottom: -10px">

                        <li><h3 style="margin-top: 5px !important;text-transform: none; "><a href="{{ url('') }}/{{ $contact->username }}"> {{ $contact->username }}</a></h3><p>
                            <strong><i class="icon-real-estate-020 u-line-icon-pro"></i> : </strong><a href="#">{{ $contact->country->country }}</a><br>
                            <strong><i class="icon-screen-tablet fa-" aria-hidden="true"></i> : </strong><a href="#">{{ $contact->industry->industry }}</a><br>
                            <strong><i class="icon-frame fa-" aria-hidden="true"></i> : </strong><a href="#">{{ $contact->organization_type->organization_type }}</a><br>
                        </p>
                    </li></ul>

                </div>

                @if($count_user == 2)
            </div>
            @break;
            <?php  $count_user = 0; ?>
            @endif
            @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to amend the style sheet to display unordered list elements inline :

```
ul li { display: inline; }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use div tag to divide your page based on columns as shown below. dont kown how you fetch your record from your controller, anyway you could use `@foreach @endforeach`

```
@foreach ($contacts as $contact)
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="display:block; height:300px; overflow:hidden">
     <?php $img = asset('thumbnail').'/'.$contact->profile_picture; ?>
     <img class="img-circle noticeboard-profile-picture" src="{{ url('ass/50/50?'.$img) }}" alt=""></a>
    </div>
  </div>
<hr>
 @endforeach
```